# Does Munin HTML output directory gets regenerated if I remove it?

Tags: munin

I've made lots of changes in my Munin server, specially regrouping the different monitored servers. Same way I've already moved the .rrd files to the /var/lib/munin directories with the new layout. However I was wondering if it's possible to completely remove /var/www/html/munin contents so they are generated again.

Answer (score 2):

I finally created a test Munin installation, copied the data and removed the HTML directory, and luckily it gets regenerated.